# JavaScript: 'i' is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to make dinamically javascript calculation for my form and I don't want to do this for each row. I am trying to do this with while loop, but here in my example ( i ) variable can not be recognized when I add like this:

```
( '<%=FV.FindControl("txt_OBR_P_1_1" + "_" & i )


     <script language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).on("keyup", "input[type=text]", function() {
               var i = 1;

               while (i < 10) {
                    var txt_OBR_P_1_1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txt_OBR_P_1_1" & "_" & i).ClientID%>').value.replace(/\,/g, '')) || 0  
                    var txt_OBR_P_1_2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=FV.FindControl("txt_OBR_P_1_2" & "_" & i).ClientID%>').value.replace(/\,/g, '')) || 0
                    var txtKOL3 = txt_OBR_P_1_1 + txt_OBR_P_1_2;
                    if (txtKOL3 === 0 || txtKOL3 === Infinity || isNaN(txtKOL3)) {
                        txtKOL3 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtKOL3" & "_" & i).ClientID%>').val("");
                     }
                     else {

                        txtKOL3 = $('#' + '<%:FV.FindControl("txtKOL3" & "_" & i).ClientID%>').val(txtKOL3.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,')); 
                     }
                     i++;
               }
            })
         })
     </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure your error is caused by javascript and happens client side? I'm wondering if your error is not caused by your asp.net markup, that is run server side (before the while loop is executed), that doesn't know about your `i`

Comment: When I remove variable i and while loop, this example work fine and calculate for one row.

Comment: `<%:FV.FindControl("txtKOL3" & "_" & i).ClientID%>` is part of ASP.NET expression, not JS one. Better to get control ID from server side with `while` or `for` loop, store it in array or collection and pass it to JS function.

Comment: You initialize "i" in javascript but use it in the VB. VB cannot see that variable since it's server side and javascript is client side.